# Creating clone of a VM in OpenStack

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, openstack, iaas, openstack-cinder

I need a copy of cinder volume, so that only hostname is changed with the same contents of as of the existing cinder volume?

Comment: you can take snapshot of a VM and then clone it from that snapshot image. http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli_use_snapshots_to_migrate_instances.html

Comment: Thanks for reply Aravind, I am looking for a clone and not snapshot :(

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have an instance that's boot from volume? You can create an image using Cinder backup, and from that image create another volume, and boot your instance from that volume.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this tool to replicate VMs. It works with both local or bootable volumes: https://github.com/sapcc/cyclone

Answer (score 0):

You can take a snapshot of your original VM and create a second instance booting up from that snapshot. The hostname can be changed using cloud-init (or manually after the first boot).